# C - while loop hanging on the condition

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'm a newbie learning code so this might be pretty simple but I can't understand what is happening.

When I try to run the following code it seems to hang on the `while` loop condition and doesn't execute any code after that. Is the `!=` operator not suited for this?

I also tried a `do {} while` and everything ran fine but as soon as I set the operator to `'E'`, again the condition seems to hang there and doesn't get out of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float n, content;
    char operator;

    n = content = 0;
    operator = 'a';

    printf("Begin Calculations:\n");

    while (operator != 'E');
    {
        scanf("%f %c", &n, &operator);

        switch (operator) {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            content = n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '+':
            content = content + n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '-':
            content = content - n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '*':
            content = content * n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '/':
            content = content / n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            printf("End of calculations\n");
            operator == 'E';
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator == 'E';` will not convert `'e'` to `'E'`. Please enable compiler warnings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic bug in your `while` loop:

```
while (operator != 'E');
{
```

The `;` after the condition is parsed as en empty statement, hence your `while` runs forever if `operator` is different from `'E'`.

Using the classic Kernighan and Ritchie brace style makes this kind of bug obvious and much less likely to occur:

```
while (operator != 'E') {
```

Also note that you should exit your loop from the `switch` statement instead of testing for `E` in the `while` condition, this would allow for both `e` and `E` to be handled correctly (your statement `operator == 'E';` is a no op, it should be written `operator = 'E';`.  Also check the return value of `scanf` to avoid looping endlessly at end of file.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float n, content;
    char operator;
    int active = 1;

    n = content = 0;

    printf("Begin Calculations:\n");

    while (active && scanf("%f %c", &n, &operator) == 2) {
        switch (operator) {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            content = n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '+':
            content = content + n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '-':
            content = content - n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '*':
            content = content * n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case '/':
            content = content / n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            printf("End of calculations\n");
            active = 0;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The classic ; (semicolon) indeed, thanks for the in-depth response now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the while statement:

```
while(operator != 'E')
{
```

The semicolon ends the body of the while statement, in other words it behaves as if you would write this:

```
while(operator != 'E')
{
}
```

causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to remove the semi-colon at the end of `while`
2. You need to take into account both cases

So change

```
while(operator != 'E');
```

to

```
while(operator != 'E' && operator != 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(operator != 'E');
```

The correct syntax is `while (...) { ... }` without semicolon or `do { ... } while (...);` with.

```
printf("End of calculations\n");
operator == 'E';
```

The assignment operator is a single `=`. Change `==` into `=` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semi-colon from while loop because semi-colon means end of statement so your program is not executing further

Comment: _program is not executing further_ - this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

couple of things.
1- operator is a reserve word, you should change the variable name
2- (semicolon ;) after while()

Check update code:

```
        #include <stdio.h>

        int main(void)
        {
          float n, content;
          char operator1;

          n = content = 0;
          operator1 = 'a';

          printf("Begin Calculations:\n");

          while(operator1 != 'E')
          {
            scanf("%c", &operator1);

            switch(operator1)
            {
              case 's':
              case 'S':
            content = n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

              case '+':
            content = content + n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

              case '-':
            content = content - n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

              case '*':
            content = content * n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

              case '/':
            content = content / n;
            printf("= %f\n", content);
            break;

              case 'e':
              case 'E':
            printf("End of calculations\n");
            operator1 = 'E';
            break;

              default:
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            break;
            }
          }
          return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the operator tip, I will keep that in mind.